# Get or Create a Node in a Custom Module

Tags: nodes

This is my first time doing any custom module work in Drupal and need some advice.  I have a django background.

I am accessing data on an external non-Drupal server to display on the Drupal site.  I think I want to create a custom field type that holds the unique integer mapped to the data's ID on the external site.

> 1) user visits `/mymodule/1234` where `1234` maps to the external data
>   source (not the drupal node)
>   2) module performs a kind of
>   `get_or_create` and either gets the node that matches the unique ID or
>   creates one
>   3) the user will see get a node returned to them (can
>   handle comments, statistics, etc) that also displays the external data
>   (which I will query via REST)

I'm basically asking for advice if this approach is tenable in Drupal and how to implement the get_or_create part of this if it is.

## what I can imagine so far

First, custom module and a url handler:

```
<?php
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['mymodule'] = array (
        'testing' => 'I am just testing',
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_view',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        );
    return $items;
}
```

Then a custom view function to do the heavy lifting when user visits `/mymodule/1234`:

```
<?php
function mymodule_view($data_id = 0) {

    // custom REST function to get the data via the $data_id
    $data = get_my_data_cleverly($data_id);

    if (!$data) {
        //return 404
    }

    // not sure about this part
    get_or_create_node($data_id);

    // then return output to theme combining both node and $data
    // this is an oversimplified render array output that doesn't
    // work mostly because I don't understnand how Drupal does this yet
    $output =  array(
        'node' => $node,
        'data' +> $data,

    );
    return $output;

}
```

The result would be a node, with additional non-node information passed to the template.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create or use an existing content type for your nodes.
Add a field (`field_ext_id`) on the content type to track your external content id.
When building your page, use [EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.org/node/1343708) (note that it may have performance implications on very large sites) to look for a node with `field_ext_id = your id`.
If no node found, create one:

```
$node = new stdClass;
$node->type = 'your_content_type';
$node->status = 1;
$node->uid = 1;
$node->title = 'my node';
$node->created = REQUEST_TIME;
$node->updated = REQUEST_TIME;

// set your other field values (including field_ext_id), as necessary

node_save($node);

// your new node's id is now available as $node->nid
```

For working with fields, have a look at [Rendering Drupal 7 Fields The Right Way](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way) and [Entity Metadata Wrapper](https://drupal.org/node/1021556).

Comment: How does the `$node->nid` end up getting passed through the renderer so Drupal knows it's a node at output? Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the entity method as opposed to the node class method:

```
$node = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'content_type'));
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$node);

 //Set properties
 $entity->author = $user->uid; // Author
 $entity->title->set("String");  //Title
 $entity->field_name->set("String"); //Textfield
 $entity->body->set(array('value' => "String or HTML")); //Body   
$entity->save();
```

Much cleaner and preferred way.

Comment: The "entity method" is from the Entity API correct?  And - I'm not creating a new entity ... just adding a content type to the node ?  All those nodes, entity types, entities, fields ... has my head spinning a little.  Smile.

Comment: Nodes are entities and you will need the entity api to do this.  So in my example the "content_type" will be the machine name of the node you created, example "article"